# How do I select a record from a Realm database?

Tags: swift, sorting, realm

how do i select a record? I did so but it gives me a mistake.

```
    func getidPet() -> Pet? {  
        let realm = try! Realm.init()
        let results = realm.objects(Pet.self).sorted(byKeyPath: **"petId" = diaryPetId**)
        
        guard !results.isEmpty else {
            return nil
        }
        return results[0]
    }
```

I wish "petId" = diaryPetId

---

I tried this too but nothing happens:

```
let results = realm.objects(Pet.self).filter("petId = 'diaryPetId'")
```

Comment: The answer will depend on if your Pet object has a primary key or not. If it does, then the answer @Doci provided will work. If not then what's in your question `.filter("petId = 'diaryPetId'")` will work (not .sorted). Please include Realm objects in the question so we have enough info to answer. Either way though, don't do this `let realm = try! Realm.init()`. You just need to use `let realm = try! Realm()`

Comment: If you can update your question with more information, we can probably come up with a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your petId is primary key for your realm object Pet, it should work like this:

```
let results = realm.object(ofType: Pet.self, forPrimaryKey: petId)
```

Comment: no, it is not the primary key. It is a variable type String